# typescript - extend class definition without constructor

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I'm using a library which isn't written in TypeScript and thus I've to use the definition file.

Within this definition file there's a class without a constructor (because the original JS code doesn't have a constructor). If I try to extend the class within my code, I get the error:

> Error:(36, 2) TS2377: Constructors for derived classes must contain a
>   'super' call.

If I add `super()` to the constructor, JavaScript complains:

> Uncaught TypeError: _super.call is not a function

How can I modify the definition file so that this code works and the first error from TS is eliminated? (for TypeScript 1.6)

---

Here's a simple example of the definition file (based on [backbone-global.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/backbone/backbone-global.d.ts%20backbone-global.d.ts):

```
declare module Backbone {
    class Events {
        on(eventName: string, callback?: Function, context?: any): any;
        off(eventName?: string, callback?: Function, context?: any): any;
    }

    class ModelBase extends Events {
    ...
    }

    class Router extends Events {
    ...
    }
}
```

Within my code I have something like:

```
/// <reference path="libs/typescript/backbone/backbone.d.ts" />

class RosApiManager extends Backbone.Events {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Backbone.events` is not a class (and should not have been declared as such in the .d.ts file). You can't extend something that isn't a class.

Comment: Ok, so how should it then have been declared?
`ModelBase` and `Router` still need to somehow inherit the methods from `Events`...

Comment: Hit same issue... wondering if there is something in TS allowing to workaround this `_super.call(this);` statement when we really don't want to call it ... or we should fix the Backbone.d.ts file for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Some might the error:

> _super.call is not a function

if they incorrectly defined the class like

```
export class InlineIf extends React{... }
```

instead of

```
export class InlineIf extends React.Component {... }
```

Adding this as an answer hoping someone might find it useful in the future...